# How to get data with projection in spring

Tags: java, spring, entity, getter-setter, projection

I have the following class `ReportReview` when I get the data with projection it gives me the following data But I want also to get data of `ratedProperty` in `PropertyRating` class with Report review , When I use this projection It gives me the following response

**ReportReview.class**

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User repoter;

    @ManyToOne
    private PropertyRating reportedReview;

   // @OneToOne(mappedBy="PropertyRating",targetEntity=PropertyRating.class)
    //private Property propertyRating;


    @Column(length=1024)
    private String Report;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
      .... Getters and Setters
    }
```

**PropertyRating.class**

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class PropertyRating implements PropertyRatingGetters{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    private Date createdDate;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @JoinColumn(name="rater")
    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne
    private User rater;

    @JoinColumn(name="ratedProperty")
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, targetEntity = Property.class)
    private Property ratedProperty;

    private float rating;


    @Column(length=1024)
    private String reviewText;

..getter and setter
}
```

**Projection**

```
@Projection(name="PropertyWithReportReview", types=ReportReview.class)
public interface PropertyWithReportReview extends ReportReviewGetter {

}
```

**reportReviewGetter**

```
 public interface ReportReviewGetter {

         Long getId();
         User getRepoter();
         PropertyRating getReportedReview();
         String getReport();
    }

**Response I get** 
"reportReviews": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "report": "abc",
        "repoter": {
          "id": 2,
          "logonEmail": "student@gmail.com",
          "name": "Student",
          "emailVerified": true,
          "address": "A-213",
          "postcode": "888",
          "phoneNo": "2342",
          "passportNo": null,
          "description": null,
          "meanRating": 2
        },
        "reportedReview": {
          "id": 1,
          "createdDate": null,
          "modifiedDate": null,
          "rating": 3,
          "reviewText": "gfhdvfb"
        },
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8555/api/reportReviews/1"
          },
          "reportReview": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8555/api/reportReviews/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
          },
          "repoter": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8555/api/reportReviews/1/repoter"
          },
          "reportedReview": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8555/api/reportReviews/1/reportedReview"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

**EDITED**
***Property.class***

```
public class Property implements PropertyGetters, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = User.class)
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=UniversityDistance.class,mappedBy="property")
    private List<UniversityDistance> universityDistances;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Room.class, mappedBy="property")
    private Set<Room> rooms;


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property",targetEntity=PropertyPhoto.class)
    private List<PropertyPhoto> photos ;

//    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
////    @JoinTable(name = "tbu1213", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "businessid", referencedColumnName = "businessid") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"))
//  @org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(
//          org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA
//  )   
//    private Set<UniversityDistance> universityDistances = new HashSet<UniversityDistance>();
//    

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PropertyType propertyType;  

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ContractType contractType;

    private String propertyTitle;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PropertyStatus propertyStatus;

    private String address;
    @ManyToOne
    private City city;

    @Column(length=1000)
    private String description;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private boolean wifi;
    private boolean kitchenAppliances;
    private boolean laundry;
    private boolean heating;
    private boolean cable;
    private boolean furnished;
    private boolean gasBill;
    private boolean hydroBill;
    private boolean cooling;
    private boolean parking;
    private boolean waterBill;



    private boolean cctv;
    private boolean maintenance;
    private boolean secureEntry;
    private boolean petAllowed;
    private boolean smokingAllowed;
    private boolean guestAllowed;


    private int noOfRoom;

    @JsonIgnore
    private float meanRating;


    @ManyToOne()
    private Business business;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @JoinColumn(name="ratedProperty")
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, targetEntity = Property.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Property ratedProperty;
```

Comment: Where I add this?

Comment: This is same field as what you have in your ` PropertyRating` class. I jave jsut added `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: Nothing happened :|

Comment: where is your `Property` class. how does it look like?

Comment: check your projection interface. It is not correct.